# Log bjob info immediately after bsub

Tags: lsf

I'm looking for a way to log information to a file about a submitted job immediately after it starts.

Normally all the job status is appended to the log file after a job has completed, but I'd like to know the information it has when it starts.

I know there's the -B flag but I want it in a file, and I could also do something like:

bsub -J jobby -o run_job.log bjobs -l -J jobby > jobby.log; run_job

but maybe someone knows of a funkier way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this falls under programming; ServerFault may be the better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some subtle variations that essentially accomplish the same thing:

1. You can use a pre-exec to do a similar thing instead of doing the
   bjobs as part of the command:

   ```
   bsub -J jobby -E "bjobs -l -J jobby > jobby.log" run_job
   ```
2. You can use the job's environment to get your own jobid instead of
   using `-J` if you write your submission as a script:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #BSUB -o run_job.log
   bjobs -l $LSB_JOBID > $LSB_JOBID.log
   run_job
   ```

   Then submit your job like this:

   ```
   bsub < jobscript.sh
   ```
3. You can do some combination of the above: use `$LSB_JOBID` in a
   pre-execution script.

That's about as 'funky' as it gets AFAIK :)